# Need to change WSL default path in Explorer from \\wsl.localhost\\ to \\wsl$\\

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, phpstorm

After some update Windows 11 started using by default "\\wsl.localhost" path in explorer instead of "\\wsl$" to access files on WSL disk:
[access to WSL files from explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmwla.png)

So, some IDEs has a poor support for this type of path.
When I open a project in IDE like PhpStorm using \\wsl$ path everything works fine.
But, then I open a project using \\wsl.localhost there are a number of issues:

- IDE cannot correctly handles files in "\\wsl.localhost", in most cases it just not see files in this location
- "\\wsl.localhost" works slower then "\\wsl$", because it try to access WSL files as network drive, not a direct access
- sync via sftp IS NOT possible, due to "no files or folders found" message
- and more

And because of this I cannot work properly with my projects.

So maybe there is exists some Explorer settings to change the type of access to WSL files with "wsl$"? I tried to find information on some registry keys, but no information anywhere

Comment: The path to WSL changed to more than two years ago to **\\wsl.localhost** this was a Windows kernel change.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, may be. But for some reason, I ran into this problem recently, up until a few months ago my IDE was opening "wsl$" style path to files. Maybe it's because of a new version of IDE itself. In any case I am disappointed, as the problem is quite common and old, and the JetBrains team developers have not solved it yet

Comment: Certainly after 2+ years they would have addressed this issue, are you running, and older version? Windows 11 has never had the legacy directory it has always been the new one that’s how old of a change it is

Comment: @Ramhound I use lates version for both Win and PhpStorm. Jetbrains has known about this bug for years, there's even a report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266154. But they still haven't fixed it, new comments on the problem were left a few weeks ago and nothing.

Comment: Also Microsoft did the wrong thing by forcibly switching directory paths, it's obvious to me that this approach creates backwards compatibility problems and breaks path settings for many programs. They could have just made the update as a new option and let the user choose which path they want to use.